# Displaying the top two of summed values by group

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a query named "QueryTotalGrades" which has three fields (Group, StudentID and Mark). each studentID has more than one mark. What I want to do is to create another query that conduct the following :

```
1- Sum mark for each studentID as a sumOfMark (Descending order)
2- Display the top 2 of sumOfMarks per group.
```

Example: let say that the "QueryTotalGrades" has the following values. 
I'm using Microsoft access 2013

```
Group    StudentID     Mark
1           1            8
1           1            7
1           1            8
1           2            7
1           2            7
1           2            7
1           3            9
1           3            9
1           3            9
2           4            5
2           4            7
2           4            5
2           5            7
2           5            7
2           5            7
2           6            6
2           6            6
2           6            6
3           7            8
3           7            7
3           7            8
3           8            7
3           8            7
3           8            7
3           9            10
3           9            10
3           9            10
```

,so the output that I want should be as following

```
Group    StudentID     SumOfMark
1           3            27
1           1            23
2           5            21
2           6            18    
3           9            30
3           7            23
```

I have tried many solutions, but no avail. HELP

Comment: What ever u have tried, share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little longwinded but:

```
select 
    t1.[Group], t1.StudentID, t1.SumOfMark
from

    (select [Group], StudentID, sum(Mark) as SumOfMark
    from QueryTotalGrades
    group by [Group], StudentID) as t1

where

    (select count(*) from

        (select [Group], StudentID, sum(Mark) as SumOfMark
        from QueryTotalGrades
        group by [Group], StudentID) as t2

        where 
            t2.[Group] = t1.[Group] and
            t2.SumOfMark >= t1.SumOfMark) <= 2

order by 
     t1.[Group], t1.SumOfMark desc
```

You can play with it here: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c3d9/1/0)

Comment: Gustav, 
thank you for the replay. I tried your code but it returns more than 2 values per group. Also, it returns null values at each group

Comment: Then you data probably differs from the sample. The query at SQL Fiddle returns exactly your desired output.

Comment: Differ but they are all numbers

Comment: Now i got it works. The problem was with null values of Mark field . How to handle it please ?

Comment: You could use: `sum(Nz([Mark], 0)) as SumOfMark`.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
;with cte as
(
   select rn=row_number() over
   (
       partition by [Group]
       order by sum(Mark) desc
   ),
  [Group],StudentID,
  sum(Mark) as SumOfMark
  from student
  group by [Group],StudentID
 )
 select [Group],StudentId,SumOfMark from cte where rn in (1,2);
```

[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ef57/5)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I got an error `Invalid SQL statement; expected 'delete', 'insert', etc... `

Comment: That's because it is T-SQL, not Access SQL.